# Cannot check my R package correctly

Tags: r, r-package

I have a own r package that works well. However when I check it, R delete me the export(predict.acb) on the NAMESPACE file. 
In my .R file I have:

```
#' @export
acb<-function(Class,data,lambda,distance=NULL,prior=NULL,info.pred=NULL)
#' @export
predict.acb<-function(modelFit,newdata)
```

In my NAMESPACE I have

```
export(acb)
export(predict.acb)
```

After check I get

```
S3method(predict,acb)
export(acb)
```

Comment: It seems to attempting to help you. I don't see a problem yet. (Unless, of course ,you are not trying to use this  predict method on an object of class acb.)

Comment: @42- Should I change anything in the .R file where I have both functions?

Comment: After installing do you see the function when you do `pkgname::predict.acb`? If so I think all is fine.

Comment: @42- Yes. The package works successfully only if I run the build option.